# CAST error in a Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

On the query below I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSetProject. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
```

It appears to be the where clause, if I take it out it seems to work. So I added a cast to the where clause with no luck. Is there something special I need to do in the where clause to get this to work? Just an FYI this is in a report that is pulling an id from the url.

```
SELECT new_projects.new_projectsId AS ProjectId
     , new_projects.new_name AS ProjectName
     , new_projects.new_Description AS ProjectDescription

FROM
    new_projects
    LEFT OUTER JOIN new_projectsteps
        ON new_projects.new_projectsId = new_projectsteps.new_ProjectSteps2Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Task
        ON new_projectsteps.new_projectstepsId = Task.RegardingObjectId
WHERE
(new_projects.new_projectsId = cast(@id AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER))
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

The id in SQL is a Unique Identifier, the value of @id is being pulled from the querystring(url). So it would look like: `&id='BC02ABC0-A6A9-E111-BCAD-32B731EEDD84'`

Sorry for the missing info.

Comment: If it works without the cast, why are you casting? What is the value of `@id`?

Comment: It doesnt work without the cast. it works without the while where statement

Comment: We don't know what `new_projectsId` is (what type), nor do we know what you're passing in as `@id` - how are we supposed to know how to tell you to fix it? [We're not mind readers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/172661); if you want us to help you, please give us the information to use to do so.

Comment: So show the declaration of `@id` and how you populate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the single quotes are coming through. So either don't have them there by stripping them out before being passed to your parameter or use:

```
WHERE new_projects.new_projectsId = CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, REPLACE(@id, '''', ''));
```

If you try a direct comparison when the GUID contains other characters, you should get:

> Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>  Conversion failed when
>   converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

If this is not what's happening, then don't say "the id in SQL is a Unique Identifier" - show ALL of the code so we can try to reproduce the problem.